# Post form to web2py function using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web2py

The server is written in web2py, and hosted on google app engine. I can visit my index.html by entering domain.com/index and I can send form by entering domain.com/register where "register" is a function defined by default.py

However, in html, where I would like to send form to the server and get a response, I use ajax which has cross domain issues. So I use "register" as URL, and it does not work. Help?

```
$("#signup").click(function() {
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "register",
       data: $("#formsignup").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data);
       }
     });

return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

By typing domain.com/register, I can totally trigger the function. What is the problem here? And the form is sent to domain.com... In browser it appears as htt[://domain.com/?email=ada@ad.com&password=adsa

Comment: have you tried type: "GET", at all?

Answer (score 0):

Its very possible register is looking for GET instead of POST
try changing the type in ajax

```
$("#signup").click(function() {
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "register",
       data: $("#formsignup").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data);
       }
     });

return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```